# I'm currently customizing the back button in SwiftUI manually screen by screen, how do I make this change global?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My original goal was to adjust the back button so it did not include the "back" text. But my current implementation requires adding the following code to each screen that needs a back button. How can I take this code which is on multiple screens and make it a more global change?

```
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

// Whatever content
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Button(action: {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The result:

[image]

Any help on making this change global will be much appreciated :)

Comment: if you are using a toolbar, you have to do it manually (although you could create a wrapper that can make easier). If you want back button to happen automatically, use  `NavigationView` or `NavigationStack` (depending on iOS version you are targetting)

Comment: @rapiddevice This is a fresh project so I'm targeting 16+. I'm a little new to SwiftUI, do you mean wrap my root view with NavigationStack and apply the toolbar there?

Comment: Almost: you define a NavigationStack in a view, which "starts" the navigation flow, and to which you want to return (it can be, but doesn't have to be root view, it could be a "sub-tree" you want to be able to navigate backwards). And then you navigate to child views by `NavigationLink`s. And you don't override the default navigation with the toolbar (at least don't put anything in `.navigationBarLeading` part of it)

Comment: Oh, I see, you're referring to just the regular back button. Yeah I was using that but I don't like the "back" text there and that's why I went down a more custom route.

Comment: Yes, no much options to customize navigation bar via swiftui so far. Some of these changes you can try doing by configuring `UINavigationBar.appearance()` (for example `onAppear`). If you do a custom toolbar thing, at least create a custom ViewModifier, so you can do something like `.customBack` instead of the whole code every time

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I went ahead and did that. It makes life much better! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @rapiddevice for pointing out I can make a custom modifier which makes things A LOT easier.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomBackButton: ViewModifier {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .font(.headline)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func customBackButton() -> some View {
        modifier(CustomBackButton())
    }
}
```